# Aborting commit due to empty commit message. git bash with atom is not working

Tags: atom-editor

why on earth i see this ??

[Aborting commit due to empty commit message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baDcN.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aborting commit due to empty commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725160/aborting-commit-due-to-empty-commit-message)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have some problems in your git configs(see [core.editor](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Basic-Client-Configuration)), but you can do these:

You can add commit message by putting it after -m:

```
git commit -a -m"This is my commit message"
```

Or you can ignore the message by passing `--allow-empty-message`
e.g.

```
git commit -a --allow-empty-message
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried this and problem solved  :

git config --global core.editor "C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom.cmd -w"

replace USERNAME with yours in your pc

https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/