# R Studio - Aborting commit due to empty commit message - when deploying with blogdown

Tags: r, git, ubuntu, github, blogdown

[I'm following this YouTube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syWAKaj-4ck) on deploying R blogdown sites with GitHub and Netlify. At the `8:00` minute mark I have to commit changes. When I do with R Studio's wizard I get this error:

```
>>> git commit -F /tmp/Cjwox9JEZ8/git-commit-message-931l81328473.txt
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

What should I do to move forward? My OS is Ubuntu 18.04, but I also have access to Windows 10.

Comment: Did you enter a message in the "commit message" box in the top right of the wizard?

Comment: I left the comment field blank. That was the issue. I put some generic comments in the comment field and now everything is working fine. I guess the error message makes more sense now that I understand the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the error message is the [same when using Git directly in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9725160/6309).

That is why the video clearly shows a message being entered in R Studio.

Only [`git commit --allow-empty-message`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---allow-empty-message) would allow you to skip entering a message (in CLI only, not in R Studio), and that option is there only for use by foreign SCM interface scripts.

Comment: Seems a message should not be required. If nothing is entered automatically output "NA" or maybe "No message entered". Maybe there's a good reason for requiring a message. I'm hardly familiar with version control. Thanks for the answer.